# Magento 2 PWA Venia - how to set 404 page

Tags: routing, pwa-studio, venia

I'm using Venia from PWA Studio and I want to create redirect to my 404 page when someone use wrong link for example "http://venia.loc/wrong-route". 
Page on dev environment when running "watch:venia"
[image]

Page when running "stage:venia", simple "Not found"
[image]

Is there any way to change it?

Comment: Did you find any solution ??